# Remove all special characters from string except Turkish ones

Tags: r, regex

there are tons of similar questions but i couldn't find the exact answer.

I have a text like this;

```
str <- "NG*-#+ÜÇ12 NET GROUPنت ياترم "
```

I want to remove all special and non-Turkish characters and keep the others. Desired output is;

```
"NGÜÇ12 NET GROUP"
```

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Related to @user438383's comment, I think, for us lesser mortals, you need to provide a precise defintion of "non-Turkish"...

Comment: ``Ü`` is present in the turkish alphabet

Comment: I want to keep a-z A-Z 0-9 and "ÜüİıÇçŞşĞğ" and remove the rest

Comment: Perhaps you've already reviewed [remove Turkish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71740023/how-to-encode-a-character-string-in-multiple-languages-in-r), though your issue is remove Arabic, which appears to suggest can be addressed via setting `options(`.

Comment: Actually, not only removing Arabic. Keeping a-z A-Z 0-9 and "ÜüİıÇçŞşĞğ" and removing the rest (Arabic, Japanese, Russian etc and special characters) So, keeping is the key but i am not familiar with regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try

```r
library(stringr)
str <- "NG*-#+ÜÇ12 NET GROUPنت ياترم "
str_replace_all(str, '[^[\\da-zA-Z ÜüİıÇçŞşĞğ]]', '')
```

Answer (score 1):

Using base *gsub*:

```
gsub("[^0-9a-zA-Z ÜüİıÇçŞşĞğ]", "", str)
# [1] "NGÜÇ12 NET GROUP  "
```